# Prove T is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ be a linear operator. And $U = \{ v_1, v_2,\ldots v_n\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Then let $V=\{ T(v_1), T(v_2),...T(v_n)\}$. $V$ is linearly independent. Prove that $T$ is invertible.

Using the inverse matrix theorem, if the rowspace of $T$ is linearly independent, then it is invertible. Can I use this property to prove the statement? If so, how should I do it. Another way of thinking about it, is, I think to use the property that $T$ is linear, and use properties of linearity and prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $T$ is not invertible. Then it is not injective. Take $v\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $T(v)=0$. Then $v$ can be written as $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n$ and so$$0=T(v)=\alpha_1T(v_1)+\alpha_2T(v_2)+\cdots+\alpha_nT(v_n).$$Since $\{T(v_1),T(v_2),\ldots,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent, this implies that each $\alpha_k$ is $0$. But then $v$ would be the null vector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use you criterion for the row space of a matrix if you like, but it is more natural to use the similar criterion for the column space. Since $[u_1,\ldots,u_n]$ is a sequence of $n$ independent vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, it is a basis for that space. Then you can form the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to that basis, whose column $j$ gives the coordinates of $T(u_j)$ with respect to the basis. Since the $T(u_j)$ are linearly independent, so are the columns. A square matrix with independent columns is invertible, so $A$ is invertible and $T$ is as well.

But reasoning like this seems a bit longer than necessary. Why not remark that by assumption $[T(u_1),\ldots,T(u_n)]$ is also a sequence of $n$ independent vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, so it is a basis too. Then $T$ has the property that it maps a basis of its source space to a basis of its destination space (both spaces being the same does not matter), which ensures that $T$ is invertible. (That is a well known characterisation of invertible linear maps, but if you need proof: there is a unique linear map from the destination space back to the source space that maps each destination basis vector to the corresponding source basis vector, and this map is clearly the inverse of $T$, by linearity.)

In passing note that I wrote sequences of vectors between $[\ldots]$ rather than between $\{\ldots\}$, since that latter forms a *set*, and that is not correct in this context. Suppose $v,w$ are two independent vectors, then is $\{v,w,v\}$ a set of independent vectors? Well, as a set $\{v,w,v\}=\{v,w\}$ and that is a set of independent vectors, so strictly speaking: yes. But that is not what is intended here, since a sequence with at least one vector repeated is never independent. So one should avoid set notation (braces) for sequences of vectors; parentheses would do fine, but I have taken the habit of using square brackets which distinguishes from the notation for individual elements of $\Bbb R^n$, like in $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$.